# Query taking 4 tables where 3 of them have a price and a maker JOIN them and get the max price of each maker

Tags: sql, join

as in the title, I want to make a query joining 3 different tables with a parent table, each of them having a maker and a price and getting the max price per maker, what I have done until now is something like this but I'm not sure if I'm having the right approach:

```
SELECT maker, model, MAX(price)
FROM (
    SELECT p.Model, maker, COALESCE(print.price, lap.price, pc.price) AS price
    FROM Product p
    LEFT JOIN Printer print ON p.Model = print.Model
    LEFT JOIN Laptop lap ON p.Model = lap.Model
    LEFT JOIN PC pc ON p.Model = pc.Model
    ORDER BY maker DESC
)
GROUP BY maker;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY maker, model`.

Comment: The `group by` usage is invalid SQL to begin with. Which DBMS product are you using?  The `order by` in the derived table is useless.

Comment: If all you need is to aggregate price for each set of maker and model, you don't need that outer query. Just wrap that `coalesce` with a `max` and add p.model in the `group by`

Answer (score 0):

this gives the bigger price among the 3 per Maker

```
 SELECT p.Model, maker, 
 case when COALESCE(print.price, 0) > COALESCE(lap.price, 0)
      and COALESCE(print.price, 0) > COALESCE(pc.price, 0) then COALESCE(print.price, 0)
      when COALESCE(lap.price, 0) > COALESCE(print.price, 0)
      and COALESCE(lap.price, 0) > COALESCE(pc.price, 0) then COALESCE(lap.price, 0)
      else COALESCE(pc.price, 0) end as Price
 AS price
    FROM Product p
    LEFT JOIN Printer print ON p.Model = print.Model
    LEFT JOIN Laptop lap ON p.Model = lap.Model
    LEFT JOIN PC pc ON p.Model = pc.Model
    ORDER BY maker DESC
```